Is it possible for me to recompile an dumped PEI file from an executable?
Look, I am trying to decompile an exe from a game, seeing how far I could get trying to port an somewhat abandonware game to linux. Obviously first step was to decompile it. I jumped from decompiler to decompiler seeing what worked and what didn't. I decided to try objdump using some advice and tags I managed to dump the .exe as an PEI-1386 format: using this string objdump -drwC -Mintel -S Blasterball\ 2\ Revolution.exe > dump.txt
Using that I now got an dissembled executable and to make sure it was still the original I searched for an compiler that would take the list of instructions and well, compile it back into an .exe before I continue porting it.
However, trying to research more into this kinda leads into just general talks about decompiling, using objdump. Instead of trying to take what it decompiled and recompiling it back into an .exe (Just to make sure nothing is lost or curropted).
I honestly just want some general answers if I could literally take the code/instructions and recreate the exe.
Manually or Automatically, I just want to know how.
-Kobo

This question is similar to: How to decompile an exe or a dll to assembly. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Sorry, this wasn't as helpful, I edited to post to clearly showed im looking to recompile from an objdump file.
